# When using Ivy strict conflict manager a package conflicts with self

Tags: dependencies, conflict, ivy, strict

I am using Ivy 2.2 for my dependencies management. With strict conflict manager I get the following error message:

:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
        myorg#myteam.PackOne;1.1.0.308 (needed by [myorg#myteam.DL;2.0.0.210]) conflicts with myorg#myteam.PackOne;1.1.0.308 (needed by [myorg#myteam.IGrid;working@MKTDEVPC3070])

Could someone please help shed some light on this? Debug option does not help explain it to me. What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
  <info organisation="myorg" module="myteam.DL" e:major="2.0.0"/>
  <configurations>
    <conf name="runtime"/>
    <conf name="test" extends="runtime"/>
    <conf name="build" extends="test"/>
  </configurations>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="myteam.DL" type="dll" ext="zip"  conf="*"/>
  </publications>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="myorg" name="DependencyLanguage" rev="1.4.+" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="myorg" name="myteam.Shade" rev="1.1.+" conf="runtime"/>
    <dependency org="apache" name="log4net" rev="1.2.+" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="nunit" name="nunit" rev="2.5.+" conf="test->default"/> 
    <dependency org="CodePlex" name="MSBuildExtensionPack" rev="4.0.+"  conf="build->default"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
  <info organisation="myorg" module="myteam.DL" e:major="2.0.0"/>
<configurations>
    <conf name="runtime"/>
    <conf name="test" extends="runtime"/>
    <conf name="build" extends="test"/>
</configurations>
<publications>
    <artifact name="myteam.DL" type="dll" ext="zip"  conf="*"/>
</publications>
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="myorg" name="DependencyLanguage" rev="1.4.+" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="myorg" name="myteam.Shade" rev="1.1.+" conf="runtime"/>
    <dependency org="apache" name="log4net" rev="1.2.+" conf="runtime->default"/>
    <dependency org="nunit" name="nunit" rev="2.5.+" conf="test->default"/> 
    <dependency org="CodePlex" name="MSBuildExtensionPack" rev="4.0.+"  conf="build->default"/>
</dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: could you add the ivy.xml of myorg#myteam.IGrid and myorg#myteam.DL;2.0.0.210?

Comment: oers, thanks a lot for looking at this! I've attached the files.

Comment: this looks like a bug, the error makes no sense (versions are identical) and you have the same dependencies for the modules. But i couldn't find anything related in ivys jira. Maybe I'll try to reproduce tomorrow.

Comment: Help me Obi Wan, you are my only hope... Again, thanks a lot for looking into it. If you have a chance to reproduce it I will post a bug report (it is not burning my skin at the moment...)

Comment: what you try: change the version of packone to the correct one 1.1.0.308 and not 1.1+? I had no idea today to reproduce it easily :D

Comment: I couldn't reproduce, but I just noticed, that your two examples are exactly the same :D Its both for DL. How far down in the dependency tree is PackOne, and where do you define the strict manager? But maybe you could get faster and better help on the mailing list. And if you get help there, post it here, too :D I'm interested in this problem :D

Comment: I suspect something that I will confirm over some time. We manage a good number of interdependent packages, so correcting/trying may take some time... We define 4 configurations: runtime, test:runtime, build:test. I've been placing at least some artifacts to config="*". After encountering the problem again in Dev i've disabled STRICT version and saw that a module was evicted by "itself [build]". Which remotely makes sense... I will check and report for future generations, in case I am not unique in my ignorance :).

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a BUG. The "strict" conflict manager throws a build error if a conflict is found. Change the conflict manger and you should be fine.
Here is the documentation listing the behavior:
http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/settings/conflict-managers.html

> strict - this conflict manager throws an exception (i.e. causes a build
>   failure) whenever a conflict is found.